# what's the default decode methods are used when opening a text file in debain system

Tags: c++, character-encoding, debian, decode

I am writing a c++ program on the Debian system. How does the system choose a decoding method when opening a text file? for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

The code above reads a text file and prints it out. It must have chosen a decoding method for that "example.txt" file. On many systems(like fedora), the default decoding method is 'utf8'. What will happen when the 'utf8' decoding failed? And I found the vim on my fedora system will choose "Latin-1" for that file after 'utf8' decoding failed.

Comment: default decoding depends on your LOCALE. If you do not have input compatible with the decoding *good()* will not return true, if I am not wrong to change the decoding is not specified in c++. So undefined behavior ?

Comment: @bruno I had done some tests. It seems that the decoding happened when calling "cout << line". And it will insist on utf-8 decoding and print out a strange character "� " when it failed.

Comment: No, the decoding is done when you read. "*print out a strange character when it failed*" that is because when you read non valid utf8 you put in *line* something invalid for it, and that produces a wrong result when you print its value.